# Remove file from Git commit

Tags: git

I just added a file in a commit which I don't want in there. It's a 64 bit version of a Gem, and since my other development and production machines are using 32 bit versions it makes sense to have it only on the 64 bit machine. I just ran this:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -a -m "Edit sorting fixed."
[master f99324f] Edit sorting fixed.
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 vendor/cache/libv8-3.11.8.17-x86_64-darwin-12.gem
```

I want the changes committed but I want that gem excluded from the commit. What should I do? I haven't pushed the changes yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git reset HEAD~1` will put the directory back to what it was before the commit. Then you can add the `.gem` to `.gitignore` (or `*.gem` if you don't ever want them) and do a new commit.

This has bitten me enough that I generally avoid `git commit -a` or `git add`ing an entire directory. `git add -u` comes in real handy to add changes only in known files.

Comment: @emm: looking a little closer, you probably want `vendor/cache` or maybe even `vendor` in your `.gitignore` depending on what's in there.

Answer (score 2):

### Reset HEAD and Commit

First, do a *soft* reset of your HEAD to the previous commit. Then just add the single file you want, rather than `.` which will add all the files in the working tree that aren't being ignored.

```
git reset HEAD^
git add <just the file you want to commit>
git commit -m "Edit sorting fixed."
```

If you want to prevent certain files from being added by `.` in the future, add them to your project's [.gitignore](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) file.